# JavaScript prototypal inheritance not working

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am a beginner in JS and have been trying to get the following code to work but it is not giving me the expected results:

```
cat = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.talk = function() {
        alert("Cat "+name+" says meow.");
    }
}
cat1 = new cat("George");
cat1.talk();

cat.prototype.changeName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
cat2 = new cat("Felix");
cat2.changeName("Bill");
cat2.talk();
```

From what I read about JS, from the second alert I should get `"Bill says meow"`. But looks like the property is not getting set and I am still getting `"Felix says meow."`

Can anybody point out the mistake? It will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of inheritance, it's a matter of accessing the right variables. Take a look at your constructor:

```
cat = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.talk = function() {
        alert("Cat "+name+" says meow.");
    }
}
```

Specifically `alert("Cat "+name+" says meow.");`. `name` will *always* refer to the argument you passed to the constructor. You should access `this.name` instead, since your `changeName` method sets `this.name` to a new value.

There is no reason to define this method inside the constructor though, add it to the prototype as well:

```
var Cat = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Cat.prototype.talk = function() {
    alert("Cat " + this.name + " says meow.");
}
```

Comment: I got it. Can you please shed on more light on why name will refer to the argument passed to the constructor instead of the actual field? I am coming from a Java background so this is a bit odd. Or any useful URLs will be helpful too.

Comment: That's why I never really liked Java. It always implicitly associates non-declared variables with instance properties. That's not the case in JavaScript: The parameter in the constructor is called `name`, hence any reference to `name` inside the function (including functions defined in it, i.e. closures) refer to that parameter. `this` is a special value and refers to the object in which context a function was called. I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: You're welcome :) I found the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) quite good in general, as well as this site: http://eloquentjavascript.net/. JavaScript can be very confusing in the beginning, but you will see soon that it all makes sense. There is almost no magic involved ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're not using inheritance. I don't see where you'd need it from your code.

First of all: your "talk" function needs to access this' `name` property. It's not.

```
Cat = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.talk = function() {
        alert("Cat "+this.name+" says meow."); //needs the to access this' name property
    }
}
```

Next: You don't need to redeclare the talk method every time an instance is created:

```
Cat.prototype.talk = function(){
    ...
}
```

If you do need inheritance, you can achive it:

```
var MainCoon = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
MainCoon.prototype = new Cat();
MainCoon.prototype.be6ftTall = function(){

}
```

Comment: `MainCoon.prototype = new Cat();` is a bad way of setting up inheritance. The constructor might have side effects or accept arguments etc. All you want to do at this point is hooking up `Cat`'s prototype to the prototype chain. You should do `MainCoon.prototype = Object.create(Cat.prototype);`.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this refers to instances of the function cat so this.name is the value of name in the instance of cat. Referring to name (without this) refers to name of the function of cat after the constructor. I think you can might get more insight after reading this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

There is a next link on the bottom of the page, when you get to the part about closures you might understand the scope of the name variable and the this.name variable.

Also JavaScript is not a class based language but (a poorly implemented according to some) prototype language:

http://www.lshift.net/blog/2006/07/24/subclassing-in-javascript-part-1

If you your child class "subclasses" a parent, or better said: if your childFunction uses a parentFunction as their prototype be aware that any chidFunction "instance" shares a lazy copy of it's parent as this example shows:

```
var parent,child,bill,suzan;
parent=function(){
    this.name="parent";
    this.array=[];
}
child=function(){
}
child.prototype=new parent();
bill=new child();
bill.name="bill";
suzan=new child();
suzan.name="suzan";
suzan.array.push("done in suzan");
console.log(suzan.name);//correct is suzan
console.log(bill.name);//correct is bill
console.log(bill.array);//incorrect, shows ["done in suzan"]
```

you can fix this by changing the "child" to:

```
child=function(){
    parent.call(this);
}
```

But that only works if object properties (excluding functions) are declared in the parents function body using the this. syntax instead of prototype.